# Redguard Waterproofing

Tags: walls

I have red staining leaking through tile grout in our shower stall. I presume it is caused by Redguard Waterproofing on the backerboard. How do I get rid of the continuous red staining, including down on to the shower floor?

Answer (score 1):

Redgard dries to a plastic rubber-like consistency and once dry doesn't dissolve in water (or what would be the point in using it for waterproofing?), so I very much doubt it's doing any staining. My initial guess is you've got something metal under the grout that's getting wet and the red stain is rust. Any chance you can show some pictures?